# Kernel oops during resume after suspend/hybernate

Tags: gnome, 64-bit, suspend, 14.10

After digging through Net, this seems like a recurring problem :).

My laptop will not *resume* after suspend/hibernate.

Under mother Microsoft there were no problems, but then I installed `Scientific Linux 6.5` - a recompiled version of `Red Hat Enterprise 6.5`. Suspend/Hibernate did not work there, however, I did not try to fix that, I was still dual booting back then.

Then I installed `Ubuntu 14.10`, walked through some DEs, settled with Gnome 3. Suspension still does not work.

It is kernel oops/panic since [sys rq commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) do not work and all I see is black screen - Caps Lock/Num Pad do not flash and no lines or underscores. Also [crash report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9408282/) says so :P.

Do I have to wait for bug fix, or are there some folks, who could help me a bit quicker?

I guess my problem is not Ubuntu-specific though.

Comment: have you tried Tuxonice?

Comment: Installing, will let you know, how it works out.

Comment: @Fabby you deserve a cookie! Can't find "upvote comment" or +rep button...

Comment: Oh, I need 15 rep. Bookmarked page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TuxOnIce](https://launchpad.net/~tuxonice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) provides the best way of enabling hibernation when the standard Ubuntu hibernation fails.

```
sudo apt-get install hibernate
sudo apt-get install tuxonice-userui
```