# Kernel panic 1/10 times after resume from suspend

Tags: kernel, 15.04, suspend, power-management, hp

I have a HP Notebook 15 running Lubuntu 15.04.

On occasion after closing the lid and having my laptop suspend, I get kernel panic when I resume. Caps lock is blinking, and the screen locks - I have to force shut down on the power button as nothing is responsive. Every time this happens, /sys/var/kern.log prints out ################# characters.

Here is an example from just an hour ago. My log has a few of these entries. It happens 10% of the time resuming form suspend:

```
Sep 25 14:34:38 dalsgaard-HP-15-Notebook-PC kernel: [15374.532010] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready  
Sep 25 14:34:39 dalsgaard-HP-15-Notebook-PC kernel: [15374.621505] PM: Syncing filesystems ...   
Sep 25 14:34:39 dalsgaard-HP-15-Notebook-PC kernel: [15374.663345] userif-3: sent link down event.   
Sep 25 14:34:39 dalsgaard-HP-15-Notebook-PC kernel: [15374.663360] userif-3: sent link up event.   
##################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################Sep 25 15:43:20 dalsgaard-HP-15-Notebook-PC kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
```

The problem has been impossible to replicate so far, and seems independent of what applications I am running. I have yet to find any pattern.

**UPDATE 2015-10-05:**

I may have found a temporary work-around. 7 days ago I realized a pattern: Kernel panic would only happen after I had seen the login screen and entered my password. I decided to deactivate password request upon suspend resume, and since then I have not encountered any problems.

I think it may have fixed it. It would seem that the problem lies somewhere between logging in after resuming from suspend and reaching the desktop. Having no password on resume is not a good solution, but it looks like it is a temporary work-around.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing, on an HP Pavilion. My first suspect is the wireless drivers, because I had similar problems on Windows 8.1 when I first bought the laptop- it would BSOD after coming out of sleep or hibernate, but only occasionally. There would sometimes be a cryptic message about "Realtek something-or-other", so I rolled back the driver to an older version and never had the problem again. My connection was going on and off after I started dual-booting Xubuntu, so I installed rtlwifi_new from lwfinger's github, and *that* problem was fixed, but now I'm having *this* problem.

Answer (score 2):

This maybe answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557626/kernel-oops-during-resume-after-suspend-hybernate?rq=1):

[TuxOnIce](https://launchpad.net/~tuxonice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) provides the best way of enabling hibernation when the standard Ubuntu hibernation fails.

```
sudo apt-get install hibernate
sudo apt-get install tuxonice-userui
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be only comment quality, but its a start:
I think you need to do a core dump. A core dump is a log of applications or modules that have crashed. You might have a bad kernel module, or you might have some faulty ram. IDK, maybe we can figure it out. 
First, become root: `sudo -i`
then check the core dump file size limit. 
`#ulimit -c` if its zero, you must create a file size (in bytes) for the core dumps to be logged to. so then, `#ulimit -c 10000`

Then go  [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-core-dumps.html), and follow the directions, which are way better than anything i was going to write:

once you locate the offending process, you can use `strace` and `gdb` to debug whatever the offending process is. Heres a short [tutorial on strace](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-strace-command-examples.html).

and here is the manpage for [ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) and [strace](http://ss64.com/bash/strace.html)

once you get a core dump to work with, post it or attach it, to this post, and then we can try to help you analyze it.